# php contact form sending email with no information

Tags: javascript, php, email

I'm receiving the email from my website's contact form, but am not receiving any content.

Here's my code:

**PHP**

```
<?php

$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["name"])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["email"])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["subject"])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["message"])); 

// recipient address
$to = "admin@deptfordtechservices.com";

// subject of email
$re = "New Inquiry";

// message creation
$contact = "Name:".$name."\nEmail:".$from."\nSubject:".$subject."\r\n";

$txt = "Message:".$message."\r\n";


$fmsg = $contact."\r\n".$txt;

$msg = wordwrap($fmsg, 70);

// send email
mail($to,$re,$msg);

die;
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

WEBSITE: deptfordtechservices.com

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: The email is completely empty, or just the places where the variables are supposed to be filled in? Does it have things like `Name:`, `Message:`, etc.?

Comment: I copied your PHP script, and it's working. http://prntscr.com/ca3ra6

Comment: @Barmar yes it does, just nothing after that.

Comment: @sloaxleak I host with GoDaddy. Could it be something with the PHP version or how the box accepts PHP files?

Comment: You're using AJAX to submit the form, but the `$.ajax` call doesn't send any of the inputs.

Comment: @DavidKryszczak I need to see what are you receiving. Please, send a screenshot.

Comment: @sloaxleak https://gyazo.com/af9c00eeafa80117b344364eeb64e932

Comment: @Barmar How would I set that up then? I'm beginner at PHP.

Comment: @anant I guess so, yes.

Comment: he didn't put the ajax code here, I found it in `main.js` on the web site he referenced.

Comment: You should use PHPMailer for sendin email

Comment: @DavidKryszczak  If you delete @ located before trim functions, as suggested by Anant, what happens?

Comment: @Anant how would I setup the contact form then? Copy and paste the stuff into the ajax area on main.js?

Comment: @sloaxleak error. "Undefined Index"

Comment: BTW, every time I go to your page, my computer fan starts running. You have an interval timer that's running something every 10 ms, that's not very nice.

Comment: lol. are you kidding us? haha. The problem is not PHP, is from AJAX. I was writing your main.js file to serialize form data (script is not passing values) but I was too slow. The @Barmar answer appears to be ok.

Comment: @DavidKryszczak  you need to add jquery+ajax code on your HTML form page and just modify your sendmail.php according to my code and check. just comment that form sending code(in main.js or where ever you have) for a while when you are using my code.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript isn't sending the form inputs. It needs a `data:` option to provide the parameters, and it needs to use `type: 'POST'` so it sends a `POST` rather than `GET`.

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, a `;` where I meant `,`. Couldn't you figure that out from the error in the Javascript console?

Comment: Do you really need every little detail spoon fed to you? Where is the programmer who wrote `main.js`?

Comment: Here. Extremely tired and determined to fix this problem, didn't see it myself and just checked the logs...